# HTTP request objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to make a HTTP request in this way:

```
 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//set headers
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text/xml"];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

 oauth_version="1.0"
oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT"
oauth_consumer_key="<app-key>"
oauth_signature="<app-secret>&"

//create the body
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<xml>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<yourcode/>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</xml>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//post
[request setHTTPBody:postBody];

//get response
NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;  
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];  
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];  
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);
if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", result);

    //here you get the response

}
```

I am trying to make the request with these headers:

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_consumer_key="<app-key>", oauth_signature="<app-secret>&"
```

But I can't understand how to. PLease help!!

Comment: Just a side note: You have a mixture of string constants and NSString literals (`"xx"` vs. `@"xx"`). You better use the at sign everywhere. And `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<xml>"]` is the same as `@"<xml>"` except the former is very inefficient.

Comment: Also, you should set the error variable to nil instead of allocating an error object, as you are just passing it in by reference to the sendSynchronousRequest method anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authorization in your case is just a HTTP header. So it's:

```
[request addValue:@"OAuth oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_signature_method=\"PLAINTEXT\", oauth_consumer_key=\"<app-key>\", oauth_signature=\"<app-secret>&\"" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Authorization"];
```

Or:

```
NSString* oauth_version=@"1.0";
NSString* oauth_signature_method=@"PLAINTEXT";
NSString* oauth_consumer_key=@"<app-key>";
NSString* oauth_signature=@"<app-secret>&";
NSString* authHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"OAuth oauth_version=\"%@\", oauth_signature_method=\"%@\", oauth_consumer_key=\"%@\", oauth_signature=\"%@\"",
    oauth_version, oauth_signature_method, oauth_consumer_key, oauth_signature];
```

Comment: Ok, now I actually get a Response code of 403, even if this: oauth_token=<request-token>&oauth_token_secret=<request-token-secret> ...is what I should get...

Comment: if I delete the if bracket, i get this: Response: {"error": "Invalid app key (<app-key>). Check your app's configuration to make sure everything is correct."}

Comment: Your app key certainly isn't `<app-key>`. That's just a placeholder for the real app key. I guess the error message says it all: you're using the wrong app key.

Answer (score 0):

**Try commenting all this**

```
//NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];  
//NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);
//if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
   // NSLog(@"Response: %@", result);

    //here you get the response

//}
```

**and use this instead of all above**

```
 NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

**Implement these delegate functions**

**Note - self.data is NSMUtableData object declared as data in header.**

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [self.data setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)d {
    [self.data appendData:d];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"")
                                 message:[error localizedDescription]
                                delegate:nil
                       cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"") 
                       otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {


    NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Do anything you want with it 
    [responseText release];
}

// Handle basic authentication challenge if needed
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

//I'm using HTTP Digest Authentication in your case it could be different
    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:HTTP_DIGEST_USER
                                                             password:HTTP_DIGEST_PASSWORD
                                                          persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

**Hope it will help**

Comment: So I need to add this to the .h: NSMutableData *data; ??

Comment: @RahulVyas: I don't think that your code is able to work with this specific kind of authorization.

Comment: I have written comment Please read carefully. I am using HTTP Digest Authentication for my web services you can try commenting the code and set a breakpoint in the method to check if the app recieves authentication challange or not.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when your are passing wrong bundle or document directory path to media.
Just simply verify your media path to the HTTP request body.