# To Play an Audio consists of NSData

Tags: iphone, nsdata

After getting the NSData of the Song I am using this code to play audio but its not converting into NSString ..Null is getting print

NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.audioSongData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

```
NSLog(@" url string is   %@",urlString);

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
NSLog(@" url is %@",url);
NSData *wavDATA = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;

avPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:wavDATA error:&error];
[avPlayer play];
```

Comment: What do you pretend it to do?

Comment: Like to play a song from this nsdata

Comment: Can you just play the audio with: avPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:self.audioSongData error:&error];
[avPlayer play];?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is on the internet, using
`[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]` is not sufficient. You must do an HTTP request to get the data, then use AVAudioPlayer to play it.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSData *wavDATA = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300)
{
    avPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:wavDATA error:&error];
    [avPlayer play];
}
```

That should do what you want if the audio data is retrieved using GET from an HTTP page.
The request code can also be found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611350/http-request-objective-c). Hope this helps!